# Получение результата выполнения стороннего php скрипта без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php

Привет всем! Подскажите, как можно реализовать такое на JS:

Есть форма, после нажатия на клавишу которой, JavaScript должен выполнить php скрипт, который находится в **includes/check.php** без перезагрузки страницы и получить из него результат выполнения (**true** или **false**). Соответственно, если будет **true**, выводим, что всё хорошо, если же **false** - `alert` окно с текстом ошибки (допустим, просто "Ошибка") и всё это должно быть без перезагрузки страницы.

UPD. Насколько я понял, у меня просто не отправляется Ajax запрос. Привожу свой код:

**JS и форма:**

```
<script>

//Check Invite

$("#reg").click(function() {
      // получаем то, что ввёл пользователь
    var checkString    = $(".invite").val();
    // формируем строку запроса
    var data            = 'invite='+ checkString;

    // если checkString не пуста
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'includes/checkInvite.php',
     data: data,
     success: function(data){
        if(data === true){
            alert("good");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
});
});
</script>

<form  method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="posted2" />
<input type="text" name="invite" title="Что бы стать участником, нужно иметь инвайт (приглашение)" class="text_box invite" placeholder="Ваш инвайт"/>
<input type="submit" value="Регистрация" class="button" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block" id="reg"/>
</form>
```

**А так же сам файл checkInvite.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET[invite]) && strlen($_GET[invite]) == 30){  //проверяем длину инвайта

require_once 'classes/class.DB.php';
require_once 'classes/class.glob.php';

$objDB = new DB();
$objGlob = new Glob();

$query = $objDB->QuerySelect('*', 'invites', "invite = '$_POST[invite]'");   
$myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); //фетчим массив

if($myrow[status] == 'active'){ //проверяем статус инвайта
 echo "true";

} else { //если инвайт уже использовался 
          echo "false";
}

       } else { //если инвайт-строка не равна 30!
       echo "false";
       } 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С использованием JQuery:

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
 $('#button').click(function() {
  //посылаем запрос на страницу includes/check.php
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //путь к скрипту
    url: 'includes/check.php',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
    //в перменной data мы получим ответ от скрипта
      if (data) {   //true
        alert ("Все ОК!");
      } else {      //false
        alert ("Не все ОК!");
      }
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      //если ошибка аякса, то выведем ее
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    } 
  });
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="button">Отправить запрос</button>
```

От PHP скрипта нужно вывести true или false, т.е. если выполнение успешно, то `echo("true");`  (для теста напишите там просто `echo("true");`)

---

проверьте отрабатывает ли собитыи клика, отправляется ли запрос:

```
$(function() {
 $("#reg").click(function() {
  alert ("clicked - ok!");
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'includes/checkInvite.php',
     success: function(data){
        alert("ajax - ok! Returned data = " + data);
     },
     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("ajax error:" + xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
     }
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос))

Comment: подозреваю что у вас просто не подключена библиотека JQuery. Добавьте в самое начало хтмл код
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Всё подключено:)

Comment: добавил в ответ обработчик... какие алерты выводит?

Comment: После нажатия на submit страница просто обновляется но ничего не выводит (так же и было до этого).

Comment: Заменить вот это `<input type="submit"...` на вот это `<input type="button"...`

Comment: Теперь вообще ничего не происходит:(

Comment: Как всегда самое элементарное не замечаешь... Оберните обработчик в функцию, как показано в последнем примере `$(function() {.....});`

Answer (score 1):

Ajax смотри, а если лень учить эту потрясающую технологию, то воспользуйся плагином JQuery: [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started).

Comment: Буду учить, спасибо;)

Answer (score 1):

Для общего развития: оператор === проверяет не только равенство, но и соответствие типа данных.
Т.е. мы получаем от сервера строку, а пытаемся сравнить её с булевым типом данных.
Рекомендую использовать что-то типа:

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'bla-bla-bla.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data.message);
    }

});
```

php:

```
if (_ОТЛИЧНО_) {
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Тут всё хорошо'));
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Тут всё плохо'));
}
....
```

Ну или просто сравнивать так:

```
if (data == "true") {
    alert('All right');
}
else {
    alert('All bad');
}
```

Comment: Ответ уже давно найден. Но всё равно спасибо и за Ваш ответ:)